# How to extract Span Tag with Beautiful Soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have the following code where I need to extract the text between the span tags (in this case 05.01.2020), how do I do this with beautiful soup?

```
<a class="list listenansicht0" href="wg-zimmer-in-Frankfurt-am-Main-Bornheim.7754140.html" nowrap="">
<span>05.01.2020</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<a class="list listenansicht0" href="wg-zimmer-in-Frankfurt-am-Main-Bornheim.7754140.html" nowrap="">
<span>05.01.2020</span>
</a>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("a", {'class': 'list listenansicht0'}):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
05.01.2020
```

Comment: I will do so, but there is a waiting time of 10 minutes it seems

Answer (score 1):

Below code will extract the desired text.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_data = """<a class="list listenansicht0" href="wg-zimmer-in-Frankfurt-am-ain-ornheim.7754140.html" nowrap="">
    <span>05.01.2020</span>
    </a>"""

data = BeautifulSoup(test_data, "lxml")

print(data.a.span.text)
```